# What is the meaning of a missing boolean element?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, xsd

What are examples of how a missing boolean xml element will be interpreted (by Java, C#, etc)?

I'm not suggesting the following is good schema design, but it is valid.  I want to make a case that we should avoid this pattern and I need some real world examples.

For example, both do elements below are valid...

```
<do><foo>bar</foo><foo2>true</foo2></do>
<do><foo>bar</foo></do>
```

... according to this definition:

```
<complexType name="doType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="foo" type="string"></element>
        <element name="foo2" type="boolean" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

How will the missing "foo2" case be interpreted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `false` unless the alternative has been specified in the schema as being the default value.

Comment: are you saying you expect Java to set foo2 = false in the missing case?

Comment: I had no idea you were referring to Java specifically, but yes, the I would expect it to set the value to false. I don't know specifically for Java, but in C#, it should.